# How do you directly change icons in cache of windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, icons

Basically I want to modify icon cache directly, without actually changing the icon; changing the icon temporarily (until next cache rebuild). How would I go about this?

Comment: are you a programmer?

Comment: I am but I was not planning on using this programaticaly, any way is enough

Comment: As far as I can tell, the format of the icon cache is proprietary and you would need to reverse engineer it yourself and write your own api to manipulate it.  The DB file doesn't look all that complicated.